# Nifi is appending additional character while reading from oracle database

Tags: apache-nifi, kudu, apache-kudu

I am novice to nifi.

I want to read an Oracle database table "ST_MATIC" which has the below records using "QueryDatabaseTable".

KEY,START_TIME,MATIC1
1,2021-07-27 01:07:28,M1

I need to load this to Kudu table. START_TIME is a TIMESTAMP column in kudu.  I am using "PutKudu" processor for that.

But I see in the queue that The START_TIME is getting appended an additional value ".0". The value that I get in queue is ""2021-07-27 01:07:28.0". Hence it is not getting inserted to kudu.

Could you please let me know how to resolve this issue

Comment: What processor is reading from Oracle?

Comment: QueryDatabaseTable

Comment: What is Database Type and Use Avro Logical Types set to?

Comment: DataType is TIMESTAMP. Avro schema is type="long", logical type="timestamp-millis". While reading from the database, I am formatting to "'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'"